# Command line to check version of a file with wget?

Tags: command-line, scripts, wget

http://paste.ubuntu.com/7159470/

Is there a way to check the version of a file using wget, and then download it if it's newer? Trying to make an update script/launcher for a game.

```
wget http://testing.albiononline.com/clients/Albion-Online-Client-Linux.zip
```

Comment: I can't answer my own question but I found it reading the -h (like I should have) it was -N that I was looking for.

Comment: On the contrary, not only _can_ you answer your own question, you are [very much encouraged to do so](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132886/what-is-this-answer-your-own-question-jazz). These sites are wikis and self answered questions are very welcome. In any case, please do answer, because we have not understood what you mean. `-N` will not give you the version, only the age of the file which is something completely different.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>`wget --content-disposition URL`</strike>

Update: This is supposed to be the command but according to the man page it is experimental. It may not work.

You can use `wget --no-clobber "URL"`. What this does is skips any files that you already have. Though I am bit confused. If you already have the URL to the exact filename, how could the version be different? I would make it version controlled/archived.

`wget --spider "URL"` may also be useful for you.

The man wget description

> > ‘--spider’ When invoked with this option, Wget will behave as a Web spider, which means that it will not download the pages, just check
> >     that they are there. For example, you can use Wget to check your
> >     bookmarks:
>
> ```
>       `wget --spider --force-html -i bookmarks.html`
> ```
>
> This feature needs much more work for Wget to get close to the functionality of
>   real web spiders.